# Php o Apache autoreferencia del server sin usar ip publica

Tags: php, apache

Hola estoy intentando referenciar por medio de `header("Location: http://127.0.0.1:8086")` al mismo server pero diferente puerto sin usar la ip pública porque solamente el puerto 80 lo tengo publico por motivos de seguridad pues la aplicación del puerto 8086 no tiene sistema de acesso(login). 
El problema es que al acceder desde cualquier otra máquina que no sea el server al redireccionar busca el localhost de la máquina que accesa no la del server.

Si esto no es posible con php o apache, ¿que me sugieren?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo como puedas identificar un equipo si no es por si IP, y más si tienes montado un servidor, a lo mucho puedes usar un DNS para que cambies la IP por lo que tu quieras, pero aún así la referencia es la IP.

Comment: La gran pregunta es como hacer que header("Location: http://127.0.0.1:8086")  siga apuntado a mi servidor desde cualquier lugar que acceda la página

Comment: Pues por como yo lo veo solo es posible por IP, tendrías que colocar tu IP publica, por que como lo intentas es como si alguien le dijera a otra persona que la dirección del lugar a donde debe de ir es a la dirección de su casa.

Comment: Adjunto la imagen para exponer mejor el problema estimado @M.Gress

Comment: No es posible, la dirección `127.0.0.1` no se refiere a tu servidor, sino a cada máquina. __Todas__ las computadoras que usan el protocolo IP usan la dirección `127.0.0.1`.  La tuya, la mía, el servidor de [es.so]. __Lo que pretendes *es imposible*__. Ahora bien, _deberías_ usar la IP de tu red interna: 10.x o 192.x o 172.x o como sea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta lo que quieres hacer es que las peticiones que lleguen al puerto 8086 pasando primero por un servidor que se encargaría de la autentificación.

Lo que puedes hacer es poner un script php en el puerto 80 que envié las peticiones a la dirección 127.0.0.1:8086 usando cURL:

http://php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php

Esto te permitiría controlar en el cortafuegos de la maquina que no se pueda acceder al puerto 8086 desde fuera.

Comment: Fernando muchísimas gracias estuve realizando un par de pruebas con curl  y ejemplos  basicos que me funcionan a medias para mi caso por que solamente trae el html y no multimedia en este caso videos pero ya es un posible camino te reitero mi gratitud vpy a estudiar mas la libreria

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es el valor de la variable

**$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']**

Esto te devuelve la IP del servidor que ejecuta el script, como dice en la documentación de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php